# Using Pyinstaller + kivy for creating standalone exe

Tags: python, windows, kivy, pyinstaller

I am new on creating GUI apps with python 3.4.4 and kivy. I am trying to create a standalone exe (GUI based) app with this code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

this file is called `helloworld.py` and is located `C:\Python34\projects\helloworld.py`

I am using this guide for creating the exe: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html

I can run the exe file without any problems on the same computer where I built it, but executing the exe on another computer, it wont open. I see some `cmd` windows flashing for half a second - thats all.

**UPDATE:** if I copy all files from the build-generated-directory `C:\Python34\dist\helloworld\` to another computer, I can execute the .exe file without any problems. ***Is it possible to execute the exe file without the other build-directory files? eg. exe file 4MB / whole dir 24MB***

**UPDATE 2:** I am now using PyQt5 - it does all what I want...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy: compiling to a single executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952595/kivy-compiling-to-a-single-executable)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are building using [`--onedir`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder) (default) and you try to copy only the `.exe` file. Short answer: This won't work. Try [`--onefile`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-file), but you won't get a very different total app size.