# PyInstalled Kivy App Fails to Run on Second Machine

Tags: python, kivy, sdl, pyinstaller

I'm packaging a Kivy app using PyInstaller (3.4) for use on Windows machines. I've gotten it to compile and work on my machine but when moving the exe to another, it fails giving the error:

```
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image 
C:\Users\<OTHER_MACHINES_USER>\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI38442\kivy_install\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
```

This works from the `dist` folder when the whole thing is copied across (as in `./dist/client_iface.exe`) and so I figure its a dependency issue I've been unable to resolve, apparently with SDL2.

I believe that this problem is almost identical to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643710/standalone-kivy-application-fail-to-run-on-a-different-machine) however that question is two years old and as yet has no successful solution.

I've followed a number of guides (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952595/kivy-compiling-to-a-single-executable/36021330#36021330) which is linked from the above post) but with no success.

The spec file, with adjustments as per [the Kivy guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html), is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
import os

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['client_iface.py'],
    pathex=['D:\\Users\\<USER>\\Documents\\2_Projects\\py_dice_roller\\client'],
    binaries=[('D:\\Users\\<USER>\\Documents\\2_Projects\\DnD\\py_dice_roller\\client\\SDL2.dll', '.')],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False
)
a.datas += [
    ('client_iface.kv', '.\\client_iface.kv', 'DATA'), 
    ('active.png', '.\\images\\active.png', 'DATA'),
    ('back.png', '.\\images\\active.png', 'DATA'),
    ('normal.png', '.\\images\\active.png', 'DATA'),
    ('DroidSansMono.ttf', '.\\fonts\\DroidSansMono.ttf', 'DATA')
]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher
)
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='client_iface',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    icon='.\images\icon_dWU_icon.ico',
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe, Tree(os.getcwd()),
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    name='client_iface'
)
```

And following the above linked I have included the following code in the script:

```
def resourcePath(path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS)

    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(resourcePath('.'))
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(resourcePath('./images'))
    main_app().run()
```

And my command in use is:

```
python -m PyInstaller -F --onefile .\client_iface.spec
```

The expected result would be that the single executable produced would run on any like-machine without error-ing or the need for the entire folder of additional files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing not obvious about `Pyinstaller` is that when using a `spec` file, most of the command line options are ignored. See the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html). In particular, the `-F` and `--onefile` are ignored.

Comment: Hi **John**, I've now got `[('onefile', None, 'OPTION')]` (and `F`)  in the options section of `EXE` but unfortunately with no change in result. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: The `options` of the `EXE` section in your `.spec` file are options to be passed to the python interpreter when you run your `.exe` result. Those options are not `Pyinstaller` options.

Comment: Try removing your `dist` directory that `Pyinstaller` creates, then run `Pinstaller` again. If the resulting `dist` folder has ONLY an `exe` file, then your `.spec` file is set up to create a `onefile` executable. If there is anything else in the `dist` folder, then your `.spec` file is set up to create a `onedir` executable, and the `exe` file in that folder will not work without the entire folder.

Comment: Okay, how would I go about setting `onefile` in the `.spec` in a way which would affect PyInstaller and not the Python Interpreter. The only reference to `onefile` in the documentation regards OSX (not Windows)? I can't find reference to this option anywhere.

Comment: The `COLLECT` section of the `.spec` file instructs `Pyinstaller` to create a `onedir` executable. I think that just removing that section will result in a `onefile` executable. The best way to create a `onefile` `.spec` file is to move the current `.spec` file aside and run `Pyinstaller` with the `--onefile` option to create a new `.spec` file. But then you would need to edit that `.spec` file to adjust other things (but don't add a `COLLECT` section).

Comment: For a Kivy app, the `COLLECT` call is needed to add sdl2 and glew deps, as per [the Kivy guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html#pyinstaller-default-hook)

Comment: That example is creating a `onedir` executable. For a `onefile` executable you can add `*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],` to the `EXE` section in place of the current `[],`.

Comment: Hello again **John**, that has worked wonderfully. I didn't realise that statement could go in the `EXE` call and I don't think I'd have found that without you. If you want to post an answer to the question I'll more than happily accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COLLECT` section of your `.spec` file indicates that a `onedir` executable will be created. In order to make a `onefile` executable, you will need to remove the `COLLECT` section. Also, the sdl2 and glew deps that are listed in the `COLLECT` section can be added to the `EXE` section as `*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)]` in place of the default `[],` that appears before the first keyword argument.

Also, note that most of the command line options of `Pyinstaller` are ignored if you are using a `.spec` file. Refer to the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for more details. Unfortunately, the `Pyinstaller` documentation is rather vague in many places.