# Pyinstaller creates many files with --onefile argument

Tags: build, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

I am packaging an app with Kivy and pyinstaller.

Running the command

`python -m PyInstaller --clean --win-private-assemblies -F GroundControl.spec`

creates a working executable with the path

`\Git\GroundControl\dist\GroundControl\GroundControl.exe`

but that folder also contains many other .pyd and .dll files which are needed for the .exe file to run.

Is there a way to truly create just one .exe file to distribute or possibly at least reduce the number of files produced?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy: compiling to a single executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952595/kivy-compiling-to-a-single-executable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are support files that **pyinstaller** can't figure out to get them included you'll have to specify them by hand.

In your **GroundControl.spec** need to find the **datas** entry under **Analysis** and add **dlls** and other files in that tuple. More info [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

It should look something like this

```
a = Analysis(['client.py'],
              pathex=['.'],
              binaries=None,
              datas=[ ('desired_dll.dll', '.') ],
              hiddenimports=[],
              hookspath=[], ...
```

The most common kivy files that you'll need to add here are **.kv** ones, as they don't get bundled by default.

A few further notes:

- you need to run pyinstaller with **--onefile**
- if you want to access files at runtime (for instance .kv files) the path for loading them needs to be adjusted. Your app will run in one place, but the files will be unpacked in a different folder. You can find the folder where the files are unpacked by using this var `sys._MEIPASS`.

Comment: Thank you. Fantastic clear answer. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an installer package such as Inno Setup to create one(1) .exe file.