# How Can I Efficiently Compress a Kivy Windows Package With Several Dependencies Into a Single .EXE?

Tags: python, .net-core, kivy, publishing, software-packaging

So, I've created a build for my Kivy app with `PyInstaller` that stores all of its dependencies into a folder in `/dist/` and that can be executed from within that folder. This is about as far as [Kivy's Windows packaging tutorial](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) goes.

The most promising tutorial that I could find using PyInstaller alone was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952595/kivy-compiling-to-a-single-executable/36021330). However, none of the attempted `python -m PyInstaller app_name.spec` rebuilds produced anything that compressed everything down to one file. Also, the `--onefile` packages were over 200MB in size, when all of the code and dependencies (including another EXE) aren't anywhere near that size altogether, on top of not running.

Is there a straightforward way of using, say, .NET Core or some other program to compress the PyInstaller's tutorial-produced package and all of its dependencies into a single executable (.EXE)? I know of NSIS, but my goal is not to have the source code sit visibly anywhere on end users' devices.